# How to list metric alerts in Azure with PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

Is it possible to list metric alerts in Azure with PowerShell?
I could only find:

> Get-AzureRmAlertRule

But that only gives me the "classic" alerts and not the metric alerts I have in the portal.

I can get all the metric alerts through the API by using the [metricalerts/listbyresourcegroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricalerts/listbyresourcegroup) end-point.

Anyone that has any idea on if it is possible to get them through a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the generic [`Get-AzureRmResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureRm.Resources/Get-AzureRmResource?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples) cmdlet with a resource type filter, e.g.

```bsh
# Retrieve alert rule
$rule = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Insights/alertRules -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -Name "my-rule";

# Retrieve alerts for this rule
Get-AzureRmAlertHistory -ResourceId $rule.ResourceId -StartTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -EndTime (Get-Date)
```

Comment: Many thanks, works like I want when I add -ResourceGroup and specify it

Comment: But then I understand is as that there is no specific function to get the "new" alerts without using this generic way?

Comment: No problem. Even though the REST API endpoint uses `Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts`, the resource type shows `Microsoft.Insights/alertRules` after creating a metric rule using [`Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermmetricalertrule?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

Comment: @KungWaz I believe you can use [`Get-AzureRmAlertHistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermalerthistory?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples) to retrieve the actual alerts for a specific rule, in a specific time window.

Comment: Ok, might be stuck anyways, I don't think I can get -DetailedOutput through Get-AzureRmResource. And the Get-AzureRmAlertHistory does not seem to yield any output, so I guess that also only covers "classic" alerts :(