# Powershell command to fetch Azure monitor alert rules is not working

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell, azure-monitor

I have created an alert rule and associated it with a VM. Now trying to fetch the alert rule through Powershell, but getting null. What's wrong with this code ?

Get-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroupName 'pacbldnew'

[see the alert rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY3A5.png)
[powershell code returning null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL0B5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a warning. The command should work, make sure the alert rule is existing.

[image]

**Update1**:

Try the command below to get what you want.

[image]

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts
```

[image]

**Update2**:

If you want to get the details, try the script as below.

```
$names = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts).Name
foreach($name in $names){
    Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name $name -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

[image]

Comment: @SouravKarmakar The `Get-AzAlertRule` command just gets the classic alert, its resource type is `microsoft.insights/alertrules`, to get the `microsoft.insights/metricAlerts`, you could try the way in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533976/how-to-list-metric-alerts-in-azure-with-powershell). It uses the old AzureRM module, just convert to Az, it should work.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar Could you get it? for more details see my update. If it is helpful, please accept it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But my requirement was little different. I want to fetch detailed information about the alert rule.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar Actually, the details should been included in the response, just do some opetrations on the output to appear them. I am not able to test for you now, you can try it by yourself first, if you could not get it, I will test it for you on Monday.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar If you want to get the details, see my update2.

Answer (score 0):

Joy is right in the way that the cmdlet should still execute as what you see is just a warning. However, this could be happening as Powershell support for newer metric alerts is still in the works as mentioned in the Official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-near-real-time#portal-powershell-cli-rest-support).

Also, as an alternative, if it helps, you could use Azure CLI to [list newer Metric Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-alert-list), as it now supports fetching elaborate results of queries belonging to the **Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts** resource type.

For example:

```
az monitor metrics alert list -g <Resource group name> --output yaml
```

The result would look something like this:

[image: Az CLI get Metric Alert]

You also get to choose out of the many [output formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) (json, jsonc, yaml, table, tsv) available with Az CLI.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Azure- home security center and settings and filter and extract all rules

Answer (score 0):

This query has worked for me:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules" -ResourceGroupName "Alert-RG"
```